# Ubuntu Server 20.4 LTS, Crear Script Autorrun?

Tags: python, django, linux, ubuntu, bash

Estoy trabajando con linux versión  Ubuntu Server 20.4 LTS, y me pidieron que se iniciara solo el servidor (ósea un auto login), y aparte crear un Script para levantar Django "venp1/bin/activate" y posterior "python3 manage.py runserver_plus".

Lo intenté pero no tuve éxito, también estuve viendo `crontab` para los momentos que se reinicia el servidor tratar de ejecutar los Scipt.

**Tengo hasta el momento.**

1.- Desarrollé el Script.sh, le dí los permisos "chmod u+x Script.sh".

2.- En el Script puse algo simple.-

```
#!/bin/bash
echo " "
echo "Bienvenido, dirección actual..."
pwd
cd /home/admin-server/control_flota
echo "Dirección actual"
sleep 1
pwd
echo "activando entorno virtual"
source venvp1/bin/activate
```

Pero no tengo resultados, ósea ejecuta pero no activa el entorno nose porque, me refiero a que no lo activa cuando simple escribo "source /home/admin-server/control_flota/venvp1/bin/activate", y se activa.

Será que no debo ejecutar un .sh? o algún otro lenguaje a ocupar?

Se los agradecería un montón, Gracias por su tiempo :)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si lo que quieres el arrancar Django de forma automática, yo utilizaría systemd.

Comment: Lo siento Jorge, como comenté en mi publicación, pensé que estabas utilizando Anaconda como gestor de entornos. La verdad es que no conozco el funcionamiento de `virtualenv`. Lamento no haberte podido ayudar... :( . Voy a borrar mi respuesta y voy a hacer una pregunta respuesta ya que me parece una información útil para la comunidad, te la dejo [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/410115/c%c3%b3mo-utilizar-un-entorno-de-anaconda-con-crontab/410116#410116), para que la sigas teniendo, en caso de que el problema con `virtualenv` sea parecido.

Comment: Sin embargo he encontrado esta respuesta en SOEN, [cron and virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287038/cron-and-virtualenv), echalé un vistazo a ver si te sirve, yo no me atrevo a darte una respuesta, porque no uso `virtualenv`. De todas formas si pruebas las respuestas y no te funcionan, coméntalo aquí y abrimos un chat y trato de ayudarte, a ver si entre los dos somos capaces!

Comment: Mira, la verdad me ha costado, pero encontré PIPENV que dicen que funciona, bajo https://sick.codes/pipenv-crontab-docker-how-to-run-pipenv-python-automatically-properly-in-cron-jobs-with-pipenv-running-django-on-a-server/
Pero sigo sin poder resolver  :/, parece que estoy entendiendo algo mal de Crontab , por que veo un crontab en usuario normal y en root.

Comment: Ya, lo que hice fue lo siguiente, primero instale el gnome de ubuntu, por que estaba perdiendo mi tiempo en modo consola, así que pude hacer un Automatic Login, Luego mejore mi Script, logrando ejecutarlo al inicio del sistema sin usar crontab,

Answer (score 0):

Ya logre solucionar el problema,

1.- Logre ejecutar el Script de forma manual con ./script.sh en la consola, lo cual ejecuta el entorno virtual y python manage.py runserver.

2.- Instale el entorno gráfico, ya que fue muy complejo trabajar sin entorno con:

```
   - sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
   - sudo apt-get install gnome-core
```

3.- Cree un Script para reiniciar a las 23:59.

4.- Luego realice un Script Padre lo cual ejecuta los Script.

5.- Por ultimo para ejecutarlo al reinicio del sistema, nos vamos al menu y le damos a startup aplication, agregamos la ruta del Script Padre, así ejecuta los 2 a la vez.

Script PADRE.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo " "
echo "Ejecutando Script Server v1.0"
echo " "
sleep 2
echo " "
x-terminal-emulator -e /home/admin-server/server_script.sh
x-terminal-emulator -e /home/admin-server/reiniciar.sh
```

Lo cual x-terminal-emulator ejecuta el script en otra consola aparte.

Script Hijo 1.

```
#!/bin/bash

ejecutar(){
"$@"
exec "$SHELL"
}

#Colores
redColor="\e[0;31m\033[1m"
greenColor="\e[0;32m\033[1m"
endColor="\033[0m\e[0m"
yellowColor="\e[0;33m\033[1m"



echo -e "\n"
echo -e "${greenColor}***** ******************************** *******${endColor}"
echo -e "*****${yellowColor} Bienvenido Al Server Script v1.0${endColor} *******"
echo -e "${greenColor}***** ******************************** *******\n${endColor}"
echo -e "*** ${yellowColor} Verificando Procesos Activo Con El Pruerto ${redColor}8000${endColor}, Espere...${endColor} ***\n"
sleep 2
echo -e "${greenColor}Verificando...\n${endColor}"
netstat -ntlp
echo -e "Matando Proceso Python\n"
kill -9 2740
echo -e "Listo\n"
netstat -ntlp
echo -e "${greenColor}***** ******************************** *******\n${endColor}"
echo " "
echo -e "**** ${yellowColor} Activando Entorno Virtual, Por Favor Espere...${endColor} ****"
echo " "
sleep 3
echo " "

#Comando para dirigirnos a la  ruta donde se encuentra nuestro entorno virtual "Esto podría cambiar según su Ubicación"
cd /home/admin-server/control_flota/venvp1/bin/

#Posterior Ejecutar con el siguiente Comando.
source activate



echo -e "**** ${greenColor} Entorno Virtual Activado Correctamente :)${endColor} ****"
echo " "
pwd
echo " "
echo -e "*** ${yellowColor} Ejecutando el siguiente comando:  python3 manage.py runserver${endColor}\n"
sleep 3
echo -e "${greenColor}Por Favor Espere...${endColor}\n"
sleep 1
echo -e "**** ${greenColor} Comando Ejecutado Con Exito... :)${endColor} ******\n"
echo " "
echo -e "${redColor} Nota:"
echo -e " - Si el servidor se Reinicia o Apaga, se Ejecutara Automáticamente al Iniciar el Sistema."
echo -e " - Cada Noche a las ${endColor} ${greenColor} 23:59 ${endColor} ${redColor}, Se hará un Reinicio Automático del Servidor.${endColor}"
echo " "
#Comando para ejecutar runserver de python3, enla ruta especifica.
cd /home/admin-server/control_flota/sistema_gestion_flota/
python3 manage.py runserver


Terminal=true
```

Script Hijo 2.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo " "
#Comando para reiniciar servidor, cada noche.
echo -e "Ejecutando el Reinicio, por favor Espere...\n"
sleep 3
echo " "
shutdown -r 23:59
#x-terminal-emulator -e /home/admin-server/reiniciar.sh
```

PD: Cuidado con las rutas y los permisos de ejecución.

Saludos...