# ¿Cómo utilizar un entorno de anaconda con Crontab en Ubuntu?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, anaconda, cron

Necesito ejecutar un script que procese los datos, todos los días a una determinada hora, para ello estoy utilizando `Crontab`.

El problema viene cuando necesito activar mi entorno, **no soy capaz de activar mi entorno de anaconda, para que se lancen los ficheros desde él.**

Así es como tengo configurado `rontab`

```
30 12 * * * conda activate my_env; python /home/rubiales/data_preprocessing.py
```

Al no poder activar el entorno, simplemente cuando trata de lanzar el script recivo un error de importación

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

¿Alguien sabe cuál es el error que tengo en la configuración de `Crontab` por el cual no activa mi entorno de `Anaconda`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes correr scrips con `crontab` como dices, pero a la hora de activar el entorno es algo más complejo, ya que surgen incompatibilidades en el `bash` entre `anaconda` y `crontab`. Para evitar estas incompatibilidades debemos:

## 1. Crear otro archivo .bashrc

Tienes que crear otro archivo `~/.bashrc` que será el encargado de ejecutar `anaconda` con `crontab`, para ello:

1. Ejecutamos en la linea de comandos `nano ./bashrc` aquí **debes buscar** un trozo de código que ha inyectado anaconda que es el encargado de hacer que funcionen sus comandos, el código será así:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/rubiales/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/rubiales/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/rubiales/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

*(Obviamente las rutas a los paths serán distintas en cada ordenador)*

**Nota1:** yo voy a utilizar el editor de textos `nano` puede usarse cualquiera

2. Copiamos este trozo de código a otro fichero, por ejemplo podemos llamarlo `.bashrc_conda`, por lo que lo creamos ejecutando `nano .bashrc_conda` y copiando el trozo de código anterior.
3. Una vez hemos copiado, salvamos y guardamos.
4. Nos aseguramos con el comando `lñs -lhsa` de que el archivo creado puede ser leido por el  usuario que lanza el `crontab` si no es así, podemos cambiarlo con `chmod` y cambiar su propiedad con `chown`.

## 2. Editar el crontab

Para finalmente evitar esta incompatibilidad, vamos a indicarle a `crontab` en la primera linea, que corra los archivos con el `bash` en vez de `sh`. Para ello hacemos lo siguiente

1. Abrimos crontab con `crontab -e`
2. Insertamos en las dos primeras lineas lo siguiente:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
BASH_ENV=~/.bashrc_conda
```

Con la segunda linea indicamos que use el archivo `.bashrc_conda` creado previamente.

## 3. Creamos ejecuciones activando el entorno

Una vez hecho lo anterior, ya podemos agregar trabajos con distintos entornos a `crontab`, siguiendo sus reglas de uso, por ejemplo:

```
# momento de ejecución | activación de entorno; | uso de interprete | script a lanzar
30 12 * * * conda activate my_env; python /path/to/script.py
```

## Explicación de por qué hay que hacer todo esto.

**En Ubuntu** al comienzo de tu archivo abra algo de este estilo

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

Como ya nos indica el propio archivo `.bashrc` en inglés:

> "si no estás ejecutando de forma interactiva, no hagas nada"

Como `crontab` no ejecuta `.bashrc` de forma interactiva, cuando llega a este script, al comienzo se sale, y no inicia `Anaconda` por lo que no puedes usar sus comandos, por tanto el comando `conda` no existirá y `conda activate` te dará error.

Con esto hemos hecho que `crontab` utilice `bash` y ejecute nuestro trozo de código que hemos guardado en `.bashrc_conda` para que así `Anaconda` se inicie y podamos usar sus comandos.